# How much does a CloudWatch subscription filter cost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I’m trying to figure out if creating a filter on every single log stream to watch for a very rate specific error message is cost effective. So 99.999% of logs will not match the filter and I want to make sure it won’t charge us for every log message.

Comment: The [Amazon CloudWatch Pricing – Amazon Web Services (AWS)](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/) page doesn't mention any costs for CloudWatch Logs subscription filters.

Comment: Is it generally assumed that if it’s not listed on the pricing page it’s free?

Comment: Yes. Unless it is called something different and we just can't see it!

Answer (score 1):

Based on this article subscription filters don't cost extra.
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/06/amazon-cloudwatch-logs-subscriptions/

> With Amazon CloudWatch Logs subscriptions, standard Amazon CloudWatch charges apply, as well as charges associated with your Amazon Kinesis stream, including shard hours and Put requests.